# Display specific items from an array that meet certain critera

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having an issue with pulling specific items from an array and displaying them if they are an item that meets a certain criteria.

Some context, I have an array named Person that is populated using an excel file.  Each item in the array has multiple attributes such as firstName, lastName, and favoriteColor.  I need to be able to just print out on the console all the people who have the favoriteColor of Green.

As of now I have it so that it will display everybody but I'm working on cutting it down to just show people with Green as their favorite color.  The area I believe is causing issues looks something like this.

```
for (final Person person : people) {
  //System.out.println(person);
  for (favoriteColor == "Green");
  System.out.println(person);
}
```

I understand that something is wrong with my favoriteColor == "Green" line.  I'm not used to Java that much so this is just kind of confusing me. Do any of you have any insight on this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you `for (favoriteColor == "Green");` does and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run if condition inside for loop to filter out your data. You should do something like:

```
 for (Person person : people) {
        if(person.getFavoriteColor().equalsIgnoreCase("Green")){
                  System.out.println(person.getFirstName());
            }
        }
```

You can add more than one if condition.

Comment: Ah thank you. That is what I was doing wrong. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure this is what you wanted.

when there is data structure like below

```
 String [][] personArray = {
            {"Sam", "Horden", "Green"},
            {"Sam2", "Horden2", "Red"},
            {"Sam3", "Horden3", "Brown"},
            {"Sam4", "Horden4", "Blue"},
            {"Sam5", "Horden5", "Green"},
            {"Sam6", "Horden6", "Green"},
 };
```

you can use for loop like this below

```
for(String [] person : personArray){
        for(String color : person) {
            if(color == "Green")
                System.out.println(person[0]);
        }
} //out put will be sam, sam5, sam6
```